# Cakephp 1.3 HABTM issue! :D

Tags: php, database, cakephp

Hey, im having this issue with cakephp, bascially i have a Has And Belongs To Many (HABTM) model relationship.

My models are Categroy and Project

bring all project data is fine, it comes out as `[0]['Project']`, `[1]['Project']` ...etc

but when i use the relationship and pull out projects with certain categories in the categories controller i get these tpye of results [0] (all project data in [0] instead of [0]['Project']), [1] (project data and related model info) this is really messing my code up as i use one element view file to render my projects is there any way to return [0]['Project'] for both project controller and categories controller? thanks Chris

Hi sorry if my example isnt clear

i have projects and categories

when i pull a list of projects from the projects controller from my project model the results i get are in this format

```
[0]['Project'] = array(data...);
[1]['Project'] = array(data...);
[2]['Project'] = array(data...);
```

this is how the data is pulled and thats fine for me but when i pull projects per cetegory page using the HABTM relationship in the categories controller from the category model this is how my data is returned

```
['Project'][0] = array(data...);
['Project'][1] = array(data...);
['Project'][2] = array(data...);
```

which as you can see is a bit of a strain as i want to keep 1 element view file to display my projects, so far my view file prints data like so

```
<?php print $project['Project']['title']; ?> //data is returned [x]['Project']
<?php print $project['Feature']['title']; ?>
```

with the way the HABTM relationship is returning data i would need to do this

```
<?php print $project['title']; ?> //because data is returned ['Project'][x]
<?php print $project['Feature']['title']; ?>
```

can anyone help with this? thanks

Comment: Could you post some code that you've used to pull the data?

Comment: Please post the model definitions as well as the code that Juhana has requested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has frustrated me too. I like to have one set of elements that can be used for rendering both "primary" find results as well as related find results.

This is the way I currently deal with the differences in formats of results.

When calling find on, say, a "Project" model and wanting to render the related "Task" list, I run the "Task" key of the results through a function on its way into the element like so:

```
echo $this->element('tasks/index',array(
    'data'=>make_primary('Task',$data['Task'])
));
```

My 'make_primary' function is like so:

```
function make_primary($alias,$data) {
    $d = array();
    foreach($data as $item) {
        $related = array();
        foreach($item as $key => $val) {
            if(!is_numeric($key) && is_array($val)) {
                $related[$key] = $val;
                unset($item[$key]);
            }
        }
        $d[] = array_merge(array($alias=>$item), $related);
    }
    return $d;
}
```

This returns a new array as though it was the result of a "primary" find query.

Comment: thanks Jamia much appreciated, i had thought of doing this but wondered about speed in the future as its looping through the results again, be nice if cakephp would do this by default, thanks will give this a go and let you know how it goes :D

Comment: great - if you think of or find a better way, I'd be interested to hear it!